# Function filterTriples from a list that are not in ascending order

Tags: list, haskell, filter

I want to implement a function
`filterTriples` that, given a list of integer triples, removes those that are not in ascending order of size.
Example: `filterTriples [(1,2,3), (6,5,4), (6,6,6)]` ↝ `[(1,2,3), (6,6,6)]`. I would like to use list comprehension to implement the function.

I wrote a function which generates such triplets.

My current code is below.

Generating the list of triples:

```hs
filterTriplets :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
filterTriplets n = [(a, b, c) | a <- [1..n], b <- [1..n], c <- [1..n], a<=b && b<=c]
```

But now I have **a list** of triplets  and I want to filter out those triplets from a list that are not in ascending order of size. I've been searching for identical problems on StackOverflow, but sadly couldn't find anything that I could use.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Gazing into my crystal ball: is it possible that you are trying to generate a list of triples -- say, Pythagorean triples -- and started doing it, and then noticed there were duplicates, and this is your idea for removing duplicates? If so, you might consider whether it's possible to avoid generating the duplicates in the first place, rather than generating them and then filtering them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to define a function with signature which accepts collection of triplets and returns a collection of triplets:

```
filterTriplets :: [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [(Int, Int, Int)]
```

And implementation using standard functions can look like:

```
filterTriplets = filter (\(a,b,c) -> a <= b && b <= c)
```

Using list comprehensions:

```
filterTriplets x = [(a, b, c) | (a, b, c) <- x, a <= b , b <= c]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Now I understand how to use lists in this case.

Comment: You can also replace the ``&& ``  with `, `